# v-model breaking bootstrap dropdown original display

Tags: html, laravel, vue.js, vuejs3

So I am currently working with Vue3 Laravel9 and I have created a component that lets me add cars in the backend . I have a couple of dropdowns that use the first option as a display method . When I added the v-models for the submit It broke my dropdowns so not they don't display the original option in them. If any 1 has any idea how I could bypass this It would be much apreciated.(mentioning that the displayed value should be the Hidden options)

```
<template>
    <div class="form-outline form-white mb-4">
        <select
            v-model="form.brand"
            class="selectpicker btn btn-secondary btn-lg dropdown-toggle form-control form-control-lg"
            data-style="btn-success"
        >
            <option hidden disabled selected>Brand</option>
            <option>Brand 1</option>
            <option>Brand 2</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            form: {
                brand: "",
            },
        };
    },
};
</script>
```

Just temporarily remove the V model so you can see what is happening

Comment: Would you mind creating a [mre]? It's just plain array with pre-filled data

Answer (score 0):

Provide proper car brands with id and use 'selected' and 'disabled' keywords.

I hope this sample code will work for you.

```
<template>
  <div className="form-outline form-white mb-4">
    {{form.brand}}
    <select
      v-model="form.brand"
      className="selectpicker btn btn-secondary btn-lg dropdown-toggle form-control form-control-lg"
      data-style="btn-success"
    >
      <option v-for="brand in brands" :value="brand.id" v-bind:key="brand.id" :disabled="(parseInt(brand.id) === form.brand)" :selected="(parseInt(brand.id) === form.brand)" >{{ brand.name}} </option>
    </select>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      brands: [{id: 1, name: 'Brand 1'}, {id: 2, name: 'Brand 2'}, {id: 3, name: 'Brand 3'}],
      form: {
        brand: ''
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for , since the display is outside my dropdown, and the actual dropdown is still not displaying anything.